# 3 ways to make a cross-domain request in Javascript

Tags: javascript, cross-domain

I already know 2 ways (proxy using php and including an external javascript file). What is another way?

Comment: You might find this [presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/danwrong/bringing-the-sameorigin-policy-to-its-knees) useful.

Comment: @Anurg, I'd like to pick your comment as the best answer (since it answered the question and was extremely helpful), but I can't select comments. Can you repost that as an answer to the question?

Answer (score 2):

You can use Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * 
in the headers coming from the server on the other domain.

That relies on the browser being modern, however.  Won't work on IE older than 8.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/En/HTTP_access_control

Answer (score 0):

There is also *Cross-Document Messaging* combined with regular XHR.

An example of this can be seen on the [easyXDM](http://easyxdm.net) example page : http://consumer.easyxdm.net/current/example/xhr.html