# why doesnt ajax between two different servers work?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

maybe im doing something wrong but try this sample on your server/local if i have the ajax.php file local and run the request local it works but once the ajax.php is remote it wont work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<p></p>



<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() 
{

    window.setInterval(function() 
    {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'ajax.php',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            success: function(result) 
            {
                $('p').html(result.price);
            }
        });
    }, 2000);


});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JavaScript can only load data from the same host, this is called [SameOrginPolicy](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Same_origin_policy). In short, this roughly means that a JavaScript Code embedded in a HTML-File on `ServerA` can only requests documents from `ServerA` via AJAX. This is done for security reasons.

If you really need to load data from a external server, you can try to use [JSONP](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/JSONP). Examples can be found via Google, for example [here](http://www.giantflyingsaucer.com/blog/?p=2682).

Comment: how can i do ajax between two different servers?

Comment: thanks, i had found this site http://sprain.ch/blog/2010/07/07/jsonp-jquery-and-php-make-cross-domain-ajax-calls-work/   and i was wondering why not try $.ajax rather than $.getjson and it worked but i like the example on the site that you gave more.  thanks

Answer (score 2):

Javascript does not allow cross-domain requests. I asked a very similar question recently that may have useful answers for you: [3 ways to make a cross-domain request in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5812538/3-ways-to-make-a-cross-domain-request-in-javascript)

Here are a few more:

- Use ajax XMLHttpRequest to call a server-side script that fetches the desired request. i.e. PHP and cURL
- json get request
- jquery ajax request http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/
- cURL, File get contents, and AJAX
  (echo the html or json)
- Cross-domain using flash
- You can use
  Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * in the
  headers coming from the server on the
  other domain. Only issue with this one is that relies on the browser being
  modern, however. Won't work on IE
  older than 8. See
  https://developer.mozilla.org/En/HTTP_access_control

Answer (score 0):

It's because of Javascript's same origin policy. Javascript was built with this policy for security reasons.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

However, you can make cross-domain requests with JSONP.

Comment: can you show me a sample based on what i have? thnx. what im trying to do is do an ajax call from shopify.com to another server which allows server side code whereas shopify.com only allows html,css, and javascript

Comment: What's the difference to the answer provided by me?

Comment: @theomega That it is of a different author (me). As I was writing my solution you may have posted yours first. I don't think it's a reason to vote me down. I'm not so silly to "copy" another one's solution, my rank is the proof.